# Reduce the number of stock on shipping (not in order)

Tags: magento2, stock

Right now, **Magento 2** automatically reduces **stock** whenever an order is placed. I would like the stock number to be reduced when the product is **shipped**. How can I change this ? Please suggest.

Thanks.